# adding points to a line shapefile at specified distance in python

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal

I want to add create nodes\points at an interval on a line shapefile let say at every 100 meters and save those points as shapefile.

I came across a plugin for Qgis called Qchainage, this exactly performs the task i want to do, but I am not sure how to adapt this plugin into my python script.

Comment: In PyQGIS you can use interpolate method from **QgsGeometry** to do that. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In PyQGIS you can use interpolate method from **QgsGeometry** to do that. Generated points can be stored as a memory layer. Complete example code is:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

feat = layer.getFeatures().next()

geom = feat.geometry()

length = geom.length()

distance = 100

points = []

iter = distance

while iter <= length:

    pt = feat.geometry().interpolate(iter).exportToWkt()

    points.append(pt)

    iter += distance

epsg = layer.crs().authid()

uri = "Point?crs=" + epsg + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'points',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(points)) ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(points[i]))

prov.addFeatures(feats)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

I tried it out with line shapefile of next image; where it is also observed memory point layer produced.

[image]

**Editing Note:**

A shorter code could be generated if you have installed in your system fiona and shapely python modules.

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape, mapping

line = fiona.open('pyqgis_data/new_line.shp')

crs = line.crs

line = line.next()

geom = shape(line['geometry'])

# length of the LineString
length = geom.length

# creation of the resulting shapefile
schema = {'geometry': 'Point','properties': {'id': 'int'}}

with fiona.open('pyqgis_data/new_shape.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema, crs=crs) as output:
    # create points every 100 meters along the line
    for i, distance in enumerate(range(0, int(length), 100)):
         point = geom.interpolate(distance)   
         output.write({'geometry':mapping(point),'properties': {'id':i}})
```

It produces same result layer (but it's saved in disk as shapefile; not as memory layer).

Comment: xunilk, is there a way to save the points in a numpy array?

Comment: Yes, it's possible but in what way? At first code, you have **points** list that it can be easily changed in a numpy array (`import numpy as np`;  `np.array(points)`). However, it'll be an array of WKT points. Before that, you need to specify your desired format in another **points** list.

Comment: The first code seems to be working within Qgis environment only right? The second one works for me but I want to save points as [ [x1 y1] [x2 y2] [x3 y3] ]

Comment: Is it possible to split the fiona + shapely suggestion as a separate answer. This is more generic than the PyQGIS suggestion,